# Spark: How to kill running process without exiting shell?

Tags: apache-spark

How can I kill a running process in the Spark shell on my local OSX machine without exiting?

For example, if I just do a simple `.count()` on an RDD, it can take a while and sometimes I want to kill it.

However, if I do `Ctrl C` then it kills the whole shell.

Is there a way to kill the process but not the shell?

Comment: which cluster you used? yarn or standalone?

Comment: As of Aug 1 2016, I do control^C and it just kills the command, without killing the shell. However, I am in a real-world cluster.

Comment: On a local spark-shell, I could not stop streaming jobs by pressing Ctrl-C. I had to close the terminal window!

Comment: I am using YARN and control + C also kills the entire shell

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Master Web Interface to kill or Visualize the Job.
Also you will find other things there like log file or your cluster working chart...

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the spark docs:

> Then, if you wish to kill an application that is failing repeatedly, you may do so through: 
>     `./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill <master url> <driver ID>`

Link: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

Comment: So is this a command from a different terminal session? bc the spark-shell will be unresponsive during a long running command.